# How can take file_id (voice) in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot

i have a problem about voice messages in python telegram bot.
how can take a voice from user and process this voice in python-telegram-bot?

Answer (score 3):

trying something like this for voice file handler

```
def voice_handler(update, context):
    bot = context.bot
    file = bot.getFile(update.message.voice.file_id)
    file.download('voice.mp3')
```

and set MessageHandler in main function like this:

```
def main():
    updater = Updater(token=lashi_bot,use_context=True)
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.voice, voice_handler))
```

as you can see in this example you can get file_id(voice) from this:

```
update.message.voice.file_id
```

everything you need is in update,
you can print update in your function like this:

```
def voice_handler(update, context):
    bot = context.bot
    file = bot.getFile(update.message.voice.file_id)
    print(update)
    file.download('voice.mp3')
```

and you see what is inside that, it's be can useful